# Accessing images via the default server of an IP Camera

Tags: android

My group is currently working on a multimedia application. Our task is to get the images captured by the IP cameras through a server (Based on my understanding, majority of the IPS camera already have a HTTP server *{I hope i'm right}, how do i access to the images stored in the server via wifi through a android application? I was thinking of using 'Network-Get" function in the Eclipse. Am i on the right track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple HTTP Protocol, look up how to establish a connect to a website and download information. Its not android specific, its **java** specific.